# object HTMLImageElement is showing but my image ain't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is a Google Chrome Extension which i am going to use to replace text like LUL with the Twitch LUL emote, but whenever i try to replace the LUL with an Image, [object HTMLImageElement] just shows up. Here is the code i am currently using:

```
f (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/O5XLFGs.png";
        var replacedText = text.replace(/LUL/gi, img);

        if (replacedText !== text) {
            element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
        }
    }
```

Any tips that may help me? Thanks.

Comment: replace function is for text. You can easily find examples of correct code by googling for "stackoverflow javascript replace text with image"

Comment: Yes, I do get it that there are more posts out there like this. But my problem is understanding it. I've read many posts like this, but none of them are similar to my code, and i don't know how to quite "upgrade" mine to that level without ruining it.

Comment: yup, as @wOxxOm said, you can't replace text with a `Image` object

Comment: I have a few answers which address using an extension to replace webpage text with HTML elements derived from that text. You can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3773011+handleTextNode).

Comment: With abit looking around, i found my answer. But occured another problem. I got it to replace the text at a specific site. But my code only replaces text that i think is stuck to the page. Meaning that: a chat box for example, (live chat in Youtube). Then it doesn't replace my text. Any suggestions?

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/GxMYC/757/